# "Most simple" or "Simplest"

Tags: adjectives, superlatives

Should I use *most simple* or *simplest* to indicate something cannot be more simple?

Can I use both? Is one prefered?

If *simplest* - how is that pronounced? (Is the *e* silent?)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Both are somewhat correct, but it's better to use *simplest*. This is called the *superlative* in grammar. It can be used by either adding the word "most" before the adjective, or by modifying the adjective with the suffix "-est". If you care about the rules, here is a quote from [oxforddictionaries.com](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/superlative):

> The superlative is formed in different ways according to the length of
>   the base adjective. If it has one syllable, then the letters -est are
>   added. If the word has three syllables or more then the word most is
>   placed before the adjective: most attractive. **Words of two syllables
>   vary: some add -est and some use most. Some even do either, for
>   example clever.** Spelling: adding -est If the word ends in a consonant,
>   add -est (quick becomes quickest). Words of one syllable with a short
>   vowel sound and ending with a single consonant, double the consonant
>   and add -est (sad becomes saddest). With words of one syllable ending
>   in ‘l’, you normally do not double the ‘l’, but cruel becomes
>   cruellest. **If it ends in ‘e’, add -st (late becomes latest).** If it
>   ends in ‘y’, change the ‘y’ to an ‘i’ and add -est (happy becomes
>   happiest).

emphasis mine. Also, if you look it up in the dictionary (e.g. [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/simple)), you will see "simple - simpler - simplest".

More than that, *Simplest* is also used more often that "most simple", you can see a clear tendency at [this ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=simplest,%20most%20simple&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) (Sorry, it's small when added here as a picture. The blue line is "simplest", and the red line is "most simple"):

[image]

It is pronounced as `\ˈsim-p(ə-)ləst\`, so you can pronounce it either with 3 syllables, or just 2 if you omit the first  `ə`.

Comment: I think SingerOfTheFall's last sentence may be technically right, though I do believe I've heard "sim-plest" (two syllables) much more often than "sim-ple-lest" (three syllables).

Answer (score 4):

'Simplest' is correct, but I think 'most simple' has come into use because of similar pronunciation concerns as yours. Neither are incorrect. 'Most simple' is less simple, so I prefer 'simplest'.

It is pronounced **sim** plest (sɪmplɪst).

Answer (score 1):

Beginning a statement with "The most simple ...", might be a more appropriate usage for purposes of giving emphasis to "most", over burying it at the end, within "-est".